# Laravel 8 on Windows and Xampp PDO not found

Tags: laravel, pdo, xampp

I have `Xampp` on Windows 10 and apached started on it. My project is did in `Laravel 8`. I want to use `PDO` in controller:

$pdo = DB::connection('mysqlPDO')->getPdo();

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `form_data` WHERE `id`=:id LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
unset($stmt);
```

When I run above code I get error:

```
 Class 'App\Console\Commands\PDO' not found

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-api\app\Console\Commands\Import.php:58
     54▕
     55▕         $pdo = DB::connection('mysqlPDO')->getPdo();
```

In `Xampp` in php.ini I have extensions:

```
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

When I uncomment for example pdo_oci I get error:
[Xampp start error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijgst.png)

---

I downloaded `php_pdo.dll` into `xampp/php/ext` folder and added `extension=pdo` to `php.ini` but still have the same bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, if you do not use multiple database connections, you should use (you can learn more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections))

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

secondly, check your database information in .env file, can you run migrations?

after that, if you can not enable any of extensions, you should check XAMPP's directory, then php/ext folder and see if there is .dll file for your extension, if not, you should install them manually.

P.S.: also please check if you have uncommented following extension and restart apache server.

```
extension=pdo
```

Comment: I'm using multiple database connections and it works. Problem is with the extensions. I downloaded `php_pdo.dll` and placed in `xampp/php/ext` folder. When I add `extension=pdo` to php.ini file I get above error